# Count total for today report case query php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've this query but it works only for DATE type. But my column type is DATETIME. How can I change this query to works on DATETIME type? I need to get output for todays report cases.

```
SELECT COUNT(report_id) ASs total_today_case
FROM report
WHERE report_detection_date = CURRENT_DATE();
```

[image: DB Structure]

Comment: So where is your query? ... what did not work? ... where is the current example data and the expected output examples?  Update the question with these details, do not add in comments, as it cannot be formatted and not easy to read.

Comment: Based on your table structure, the column `report_detection_date` is actually `DATE` datatype. I tell you what, how about you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE report;` and post the result into the question. That'll give a more comprehensive table structure info.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to format the report_detection_date:

```
SELECT COUNT(report_id) as total_today_case
FROM report
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(report_detection_date, "%Y-%m-%d") = CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: Best to avoid using DATE_FORMAT() as the query is not [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to count items that meet a specific condition on a table/view? If so, I don't think the db structure would matter. We'd need to understand what you need counted and the field names. After that it would be a simple `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM table_abc WHERE condition` situation.

Answer (score 0):

> where report_detection_date = CURRENT_DATE();

You're comparing [apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges). CURRENT_DATE() has a time value of "00:00:00" (midnight). So it never equals a date *and* time value, *except* at midnight

| Column Value | Current_Date() | Is Equal? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | YES |
| 2022-03-08 08:12:14 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | NO |
| 2022-03-08 14:15:22 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | NO |
| 2022-03-08 18:15:22 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | NO |
| 2022-03-08 23:15:22 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | NO |
| 2022-03-08 23:59:59 | 2022-03-08 00:00:00 | NO |

To keep the query [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), the better way to query a datetime field is:

```
 WHERE ColumnName >= {TodaysDateAtMidnight}
 AND   ColumnName < {TomorrowsDateAtMidnight}
```

.. or more specifically

```
 WHERE ColumnName >= CURRENT_DATE() 
 AND   ColumnName < Date_Add(CURRENT_DATE(), interval 1 DAY)
```